# How to retrieve this programmatically? android:id="@+id/topRight"?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

How to retrieve the value "topRight" on this function on the layout? I need to get this value in order for me to know the name of the container so that i can set the the arrangement of my child. I tried to use getId() but it returns an integer of course not the value "topRight". Please help guys.

```
android:id="@+id/topRight
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define an ID in your layout, it simply modifies the auto-created R file with a new field. The name you specified will be the name of the variable (R.id.topRight).

I guess you might be able to access the name of the variable via some reflection magic, but I feel like you're going about this in a wrong way.

IDs are used to reference the view from the layout and create instances during runtime.
If you want to have some string stored in the layout elements which you can use to determine what view you'd like to use, I would probably go with the "Tag" property rather than ID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Gil Moshayof, I get your point. I tried your style by adding the function android:tag="topRight" on my container. Then when my program points to that container, I use this code to retrieve the "topRight".  'containerName = (String) v.getTag();' v = my container. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this, I have a textView with `editTextUserName` as an `id` so I get its value like the one I posted. Try it, I hope it works for you.

```
EditText editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
    android:hint="User Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: it's not asked by the user

Comment: What I'm thinking, if the program is already pointed to the container topRight. Then cast the container to v. The container =v.getIdOfContainer() [somtthing like this].  So the value of the container is "topRight". If that is even possible.